# Can data collection be turned off completely in windows 10 enterprise?

Tags: windows-10

Tonight I read another one: http://21stcenturywire.com/2016/04/07/windows-10-is-stealing-your-bandwidth-you-might-want-to-delete-it/.

In the past I read about the fact that it sends usage information.

To be specific, can the telemetry and other data collection be turned off completely in win 10 enterprise, and if the answer is yes, where/how would I do it?

Thanks

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I edited my question to be specific. I am not collecting people that dislike windows 10. I am interested in turning off **completely** any data collection from my workstation to the MS servers.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: You were right about the title, I also changed the title.

Comment: Good improvements! Now it really looks like a question. Only thing you still need to do is to remove rude parts and keep focusing on what's really important and related to your question.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Done.

Answer (score -1):

This rather nifty tool appears to do a good job of telling windows 10 to shutup.

https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10

Some options may affect your end-user experience though, so be prepared.

---------------------------------------- 20170601

GPEDIT > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Cloud Content
"Turn off Microsoft consumer experiences"

> Data Collection and Preview Builds.

"Allow Telemetry"
"Configure Connected User Experiences and Telemtry" might be use to point it to a proxy you control to see if it still leaks.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @davidgo: I actually welcome any script/program with source code available, that can automate the process of turning off the telemetry (i.e. data collection) completely. Not sure if that is the case but I will check it out tonight.

Comment: @costa Its great that this answer helps you then, but you really should add this to your question if thats part of what you are asking !

Comment: @davidgo: well, it's kind of implied that I am not expecting just a yes/no answer and I thought the answer would include, something like "yes you can do it, and you can go here (windows management console add-in, registry etc.) to do it, or use a script or a tool that is popular ... " and so on.

Comment: @davidgo: I modified the question to clarify.

Comment: While not specfically for this question. I am getting closer to doing it but it's a mess at the moment. I have scripts to disable services, firewall rules and some gpedits. There are a couple of firewall rules you could try disabling and see if that helps.